# C++ ToUnicodeEx() not recognizing shift key unless i have a messgaebox()

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, hook

im having a bit of trouble writing a keyboard hook in C++.

I can read keystrokes but im trying to using ToUnicodeEx() to convert keystrokes when shift key is pressed. 
In the code i have so far i have

```
i = ToUnicodeEx(keyboard.vkCode, keyboard.scanCode, (PBYTE)&keyState, (LPWSTR)&keybuff, sizeof(keybuff) / 16, 0,keyboardlayout);
MessageBox(MainnhWnd,keybuff, L"message", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
```

with this 'MessageBox' line when I press Shift+2 i get two message boxes pops up, the first is blank for the shift key, the second shows a '@' character. This is expected.

But if i remove this messagebox, the ToUnicodeEx() function converts the keystroke as if the shift key had not been used. I can see this by either setting a breakpoint, with a hit counter, or outputting the character to an edit box in my program windows.

Also when i include the MsgBox line and use the CapLock, my letters change accordingly but after i remove the msgbox line it only uses the state of the cap lock at the time my program starts (cap locks is on when programm starts, all letters are capital, vice verse, caps off when programm starts all letters are small,, even if i change the cap lock state)

Anyone know why my hook just remembers the keyboard state at start, unless i include the  msgbox?

My hook is set like:

```
theHook = SetWindowsHookEx ( WH_KEYBOARD_LL, (HOOKPROC) KeyEvent, exe, 0);
```

and my hook callback function is:

```
DLLEXPORT LRESULT CALLBACK KeyEvent(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
if (nCode>=0) {
    int i = 0;
    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT keyboard;
    WCHAR keybuff[256]= {0};

    if ((wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)|| (wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN)||(wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP)) {
        keyboard = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam);
        if (keyboard.vkCode == VK_RETURN) {
            i += wsprintf (((LPWSTR)keybuff + i),L"[Return]\r\n");
        }
        else {
            HKL keyboardlayout = GetKeyboardLayout(0);
            GetKeyboardState((PBYTE)&keyState);
            i = ToUnicodeEx(keyboard.vkCode, keyboard.scanCode, (PBYTE)&keyState, (LPWSTR)&keybuff, sizeof(keybuff) / 16, 0,keyboardlayout);

            MessageBox(MainnhWnd,keybuff, L"message", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        }
        if (keybuff>0) {
            addToEditBox(keybuff);
        }
    }
}
return CallNextHookEx(theHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: GetKeyboardLayout and GetKeyState return the keyboard layout and state of *your* process.  Not the one whose going to get the keyboard message.  You can't reliably use ToUnicodeEx(), a global hook with WH_KEYBOARD would be required.

Comment: @HansPassant I think that you can. This is a global hook, so the function is in a DLL, and that DLL gets _injected_ into the original process. So those functions should work as expected.

Comment: @rodrigo - WH_KEYBOARD_LL is not a global hook.  No DLL is injected, Windows calls your hook callback in your own process before adding the message to the message queue of the window that has the foreground.  The OP discovered that MessageBox works because it jerks the focus away from that window.

Comment: @HansPassant - Actually, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx), WH_KEYBOARD_LL is a global-only hook. Maybe the low-level hooks are different than other global hooks, and no DLL is required (I didn't test it). But I don't see any reference to this in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation of [ToUnicodeEx function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646322%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you should provide a pointer to a 256-byte array that contains the current keyboard state (`const BYTE *lpKeyState`). Each element (byte) in the array contains the state of one key. If the high-order bit of a byte is set, the key is down.

Before you call `ToUnicodeEx`, you should set this array like this (pseudocode):

```
enum Keys
{
    ShiftKey    = 16, // shift
    ControlKey  = 17, // ctrl
    Menu        = 18, // alt
    Capital     = 20, // caps lock
};

BYTE keyState[256]= {0};

if (Control key down)
    keyState[Keys::ControlKey] = 0x80;

if (Shift key down)
    keyState[Keys::ShiftKey] = 0x80;

if (Alt key down)
    keyState[Keys::Menu] = 0x80;

if (Caps lock ON)
    keyState[Keys::Capital] = 0x01;
```

And when keyState array is set, then you can call:

```
ToUnicodeEx(keyboard.vkCode, keyboard.scanCode, (PBYTE)&keyState, (LPWSTR)&keybuff, sizeof(keybuff) / 16, 0,keyboardlayout);
```

I have been working with `ToUnicodeEx` function just like this and it worked fine.
Hope this will help you ;)

Comment: Thanks this worked great. I thought is was something to do with the keyState variable, but i was thinking GetKeyboardState() updated it. now I just gotta get it the recognize if caps lock is active or not, but that shouldnt be too difficult.