# Translate vkCode and scanCode to meaningful character

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I'm trying to translate the given vkCode and scanCode to actual characters, based on the keyboard. Example of what I'm trying to achieve is translating <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to '@', <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to '!' etc., but based on the current keyboard layout. I've managed to get it working briefly, but after an unknown change it's no longer working. Here is what I currently have:

```
unsigned char btKeys[256] = {0};
GetKeyboardState(btKeys);
HKL keyboardLayout = GetKeyboardLayout(0);

wchar_t szBuffer[2] = {0};
if (ToUnicodeEx(vkCode, scanCode, btKeys, szBuffer, 2, 0, keyboardLayout)) {
    if (iswcntrl(szBuffer[0])) {
        sendControl(szBuffer[0]);
    } else {
        sendCharacter(szBuffer[0]);
    }
}
```

But for some reason I only get back the same character as was sent in via the vkCode (for example pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> yields only '1')

How can I get ToUnicodeEx to return the correct value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ ToUnicodeEx() not recognizing shift key unless i have a messgaebox()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046817/c-tounicodeex-not-recognizing-shift-key-unless-i-have-a-messgaebox)

Comment: what virtual keys and scan codes are you using?